# Unable to access subsites through code but I can in the browser

Tags: csom, sub-site

I need to get a list of subsites from a site collection.

I can navigate to the site and click on **subsites** and it displays all the subsites, but when I try using this code

```
public WebCollection GetSubSites()
{
    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(baseUrl))
    {
        clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
        var web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web, website => website.Webs);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var site in web.Webs)
        {
            var newPath = site.ServerRelativeUrl;
        }
        return web.Webs;
    }
}
```

I get

> "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

when calling `ExecuteQuery()`

Even though I'm using the same account.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subsites that are displayed on the UI are permission trimmed.

So, there could be subsites to which you might not have access. The `website.Webs` will only work if you are site collection admin or owner. Else it won't work and throws the access denied error that you are having.

So, you can use the `GetSubwebsForCurrentUser` method to get the permission trimmed subsites.

Modify your code as below:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(baseUrl))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
    var web = clientContext.Web;

    var subWebs = clientContext.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

    clientContext.Load(subWebs);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();   

    foreach (var site in subWebs)
    {
        var newPath = site.ServerRelativeUrl;
    }
    return subWebs;
}
```

Reference - [Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getsubwebsforcurrentuser.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to collect the names of the SubSites which the user does not have access to?